# Data Perturbation - Model robustness test

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, validation, robust

I came across with presentation about  robustness test recently and I didn't exactly understand how to apply it to ML model (not DL).
The presentation show a graph:

- x-axis - some metric, for example accuracy
- y-axis - 'r' - how much perturbation is shown in the data.

---

My question -

Is it common thing for validating you're model?
How do I implement such graph? I just add randomness to data with a certain probability and test the success?
If so, the process is to let each row add randomness in probability 'r' to a particular feature or to multiple?

Thanks for the help,
I would also happy for references to the subject

Answer (score 0):

Such a graph combining accuracy versus its variance is interesting, when the perturbation (variance) in the data is known. It seems that you are building classifiers. You can vary many factors in this process:

- Varying the subset of feature variables used,
- Varying the model complexity

The graph will then show different combinations of a so-called ***bias-variance tradeoff***. A more complex model, with more parameters, can model the underlying data mechanism more precisely. But the model variance increases too, thereby making the risk of overfitting larger.

You need to have a well-formed expression for this perturbation/variance, which is derived for a number of statistical classifiers: linear discriminant, quadratic discriminant and logistic regression. For most other types of classifiers you will need to conduct Monte Carlo simulations to provide estimates of the variance of the accuracy.